# Building mobile app derivative of Rails web app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ios

How does one approach building the mobile app version of one's Rails app, with little to no mobile development experience? iOS, Android, one or the other, or both.

Comment: Do you really need a native app? Just adjust your design/CSS, etc. to support mobile devices, and you will be done.

Comment: definitely need a native app, [rhomobile](http://www.rhomobile.com) looks like a good option

Comment: If you don't mind sharing, why? See updated answer for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to create (private) APIs for services your web app provides. The de facto standard for Android apps is REST-like endpoints that accept/return JSON. You can use whatever Ruby REST framework works best. Then you need to consider how you would authenticate Android apps, if needed. Do you use the same authentication database? Can you allow anonymous access, what parts of the app do you expose, etc.

Finally, you need to build the frontend. A few options here:

- learn Android
- hire someone to do it
- use a framework that lets you develop using Web(-like) technologies: Thitanium, Rhodes, etc. The upside is that you get to use what you know and might also get an iOS app for free. 
  The downside is that you can never get the native performance, and look-and-feel might not be completely Android-like (never used Rhodes, so maybe it does this well enough, but still)

Comment: mainly considering development for iOS, android just happened to be the first tag displayed. less worried about android, more about iOS. But yes, these all sound like great strategic options. I just need to learn more. I want to make sure that we allow users to share on our site on their mobile device as well as the web. I dont want to limit to one medium or another.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using http://www.rhomobile.com/.